# Invalid regex in Angular ( UAE Phone Number Validation )

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, angular-reactive-forms

```
selectedPhoneNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?!2)((?:2|3|4|5|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7,})$')])
```

Error:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:+971|00971|0)(?!2)((?:2|3|4|5|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7,})$/: Nothing to repeat
```

Comment: I think `+` should be escaped. `\+`

Comment: You need to give your regex as an actual RegExp type, i.e. `pattern(/^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?!2)((?:2|3|4|5|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7,})$/)` instead of a string.